# Creating xml from API response

Tags: c#, json, xml, jsonresponse

I have the following application for making a GET request which returns data in JSON format:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        RunAsync().Wait();
    }

    static async Task RunAsync()
    {
        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            //Send HTTP request
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri("httpMyURI");
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

            HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("api/people/.....");

            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                var person = response.Content.ReadAsAsync<IEnumerable<Persons>>().Result;

                foreach (var i in person)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("{0}\t{1}-{2}", i.FirstName, i.LastName, i.Peopleid); 
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

class Persons
{
    public string Peopleid { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

How can i create an xml file from the results that i get? I guess i first have to convert the JSON to xml then create an XML file?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this easily enough using a the Newtonsoft Json.NET library. 
See an example of this in operation :http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/convertingjsonandxml.htm

The line you are after would be

```
XmlDocument doc = (XmlDocument)JsonConvert.DeserializeXmlNode(json);
```

Comment: What argument should i insert in the DeserializeXmlNode method?

Comment: Your json string which you received from your response. So it would be something like 
`XmlDocument doc = (XmlDocument)JsonConvert.DeserializeXmlNode(response.Content);`

Comment: i used response.Content.ToString() as an argument and it seemed to work, but then i get an runtime error saying:

"Unhandled exception [......] Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: $. Path ' ', line 0, position 0.

It also refers to my 'XmlDocument doc =[..] line and Runasync().Wait(); line. Does it have anything to do with:

"Because valid XML must have one root element, the JSON passed to DeserializeXmlNode should have one property in the root JSON object" ?